# Easiest way to post twitter status in android

Tags: android, twitter

What is the easiest(less code) way to post status on twitter?

Comment: twitter.com ; log in ; type in the "What's on your mind" box ; click 'Submit'. Zero code!

Comment: I mean from andorid :) "Andorid" in title :))

Answer (score 0):

Any standard Java twitter library should work fine.

[Link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Flibraries&ei=j_vlTNPZPIL78Abj2amkCQ&usg=AFQjCNE0I1A_SS5WCC1femyAslNIXnPYpQ)